# Modelica (Dymola) Declaration with Formula - What Is This?

Tags: modelica, dymola

What type of declaration is this?

`Real x = time^2;`

I can put it in a `model` before any `equation` or `algorithm` section.

The issue for me is that it is not a static `parameter`, but rather it has a formula attached to it that works non-statically - the value is set every time step.

What kind of declaration is it? Short model or short function definition? New instances of a class? A 'type' class?

Any help (especially with a reference to either Fritzon's or Tiller's book) will help me sleep at night.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a binding equation in a variable declaration and it will become a normal equation during compilation of the model. See https://modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec34.pdf, chapter 8.

Comment: Thanks, Adrian. It certainly acted like it was being put into the equation section (not an algorithm section, I checked that). After looking at chapter 8 of the spec, I can also see that it is more clear to put equations into the equation section, and not tuck them away behind a variable definition. (Maybe this is why Fritzson includes the possibility of binding equations (4.2.1), but includes no examples.)

Comment: The reason to use binding equations is that you can modify them. Extend from the class and change the equation.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to modify the variable the Dialog annotation might be convenient, e.g., `Real x = time^2 annotation(Dialog);`